# How to specify a caption outside of figure element

Tags: html, accessibility, figure, figcaption

I have a situation where I need physically separate a caption from the associated figure, e.g. this sort of markup:

```html
<figure>
  <img src="…" alt="…"/>
</figure>

…later in the code…

<figcaption>
  Caption text
<figcaption>
```

This isn't semantically correct ([there are existing SO questions addressing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738689/can-the-figcaption-be-used-without-its-parent-figure-element)), and it produces a validation error. Given that, I'm wondering what the appropriate way to represent this would be (considering markup and accessibility).

Ideally, there would be some sort of attribute (like the `label` elements `for` attribute) that would let you associate a `figcaption` with a `figure`. Currently I am using an `aria-describedby` attribute (see below), but I'm not sure if this is accurate either.

```html
<figure aria-describedby="caption">
  <img src="…" alt="…"/>
</figure>

…later in the code…

<div id="caption">
  Caption text
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could approach this, either by adding a role and using `aria-labelledby`, or with JavaScript.

**Method 1 - HTML Only**

The `aria-labelledby` attribute is only recognized on form controls (e.g. buttons, inputs, checkboxes, etc.) or on elements that have a `role` attribute assigned. Without either of these conditions, the [accessible name computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.2/) will not be calculated on the element.

```
<figure role="region" aria-labelledby="caption-text">
    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="your image alt text" />
</figure>

<p>…later in the code…</p>

<div id="caption-text">Caption text</div>
```

In my testing on NVDA/Chrome this works as long as the `alt` attribute on the image is not empty.  I would strongly recommend testing this using different browsers and screen-readers before deploying to a production environment for the reason that it's essentially a `label` on a non-interactive element.

**Method 2 - JavaScript and CSS**

This method is more inline with your original question. It produces a non-visual `figcaption` element as a child of the `figure` element.

```
<style>
    .sr-only {
        clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
        clip-path: inset(50%);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>

<figure id="fig">
    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="your image alt text" />
</figure>

<p>…later in the code…</p>

<div id="caption-text" aria-hidden="true">Caption text</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        
        // create a figcaption element
        const caption = document.createElement("figcaption")
        
        // get innerText from div#caption-text and add to new figcaption element
        caption.innerText = document.getElementById("caption-text").innerText
        
        // assign a class to visually hide
        caption.className = "sr-only"

        // append figcaption to the figure element
        document.getElementById("fig").appendChild(caption)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Method 2 won't actually work in this case because the caption needs to be separated from the `<figure>` in the code. I'll give option 1 a shot. Any thoughts on `aria-describedby`? Is that an incorrect method?

Comment: I couldn't get `aria-describedby` to work on non-interactive elements, whereas `aria-labelledby` did. The purpose should be similar, but again - this is a `label` on a non-interactive element, so it's hacky. You should absolutely do your due diligence in testing before deploying something like this being used in an off-label implementation.

Comment: I've edited my "Method 2" to hopefully be more of what you want.  The "Caption text" will no longer be visible next to the image, and the "Caption text" will only be read aloud by screen readers once.